# Entries with dates, loop through and make graph for each date

Tags: javascript

I have 700 entries in a multiarray with a date on each.

I have to sort them into the different dates, so the 700 entries, there may only be only 15 unique dates.

The problem is that i do not know if there is 7 or 28 unique dates.

So how do i loop through all the entries and push them into a date specific array and afterwards foreach dates.

**I know how to do it in PHP.
It would look something like this:**

```
$dates = array();
foreach($entry in $entries){
    $date = $entry['date'];
    $dates[$date] = $emtry;
}
foreach($day in $dates){
    foreach($entry in $day){
         echo $entry['title'];
    }
}
```

How do you do that in Javascript?

Because it is not possible to put characters as a array key..

Comment: var dates = [ ]; dates[entry] is valid in JS.

Answer (score 1):

JS version would be something like this:

```
var dates = [];
for (entry in entries){
    date = entry['date'];
    dates[date] = entry;
}
for (day in dates){
    for (entry in day){
         document.writeln (entry['title']);
    }
}
```